# PHP: File Upload only POST the path name

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, file-browser

Is there a way to have a file browser that just sets a PHP variable to the path of the file.

I'm trying to just get the path of a video file I have, and uploading the whole video is a waste of time.

Comment: Where is the video file located - on your computer or one a web server?

Comment: Computer. Local

Comment: Since you are accessing the file locally then it is not available to php. You will need to look at the JavaScript File API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File and some examples on using the api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Thanks! Something along these lines will do it.